# jquery click function always fires on second click

Tags: jquery, function, click, touch, live

I have this click function in combination with cookie.js:

```
$("#mobileBar").show();

    var cS = $.cookie("sidebar");
    if(cS == "close") {
        $(".sidebar").css("left", "-44px");
        $("#mobileBar")
                    .css("left","0px")
                    .addClass("active");
        $(".sidecontent")
                    .css("left","-225px")
                    .hide();
    }

$("#mobileBar").on("click", function(){
        var $theElem = $(this);
        if (!$theElem.attr('data-toggled') || $theElem.attr('data-toggled') == 'off') {

           $theElem.attr('data-toggled','on')
                   .animate({left: "0px"})
                   .addClass("active");
            $.cookie("sidebar", "close", { expires: 7, path: "/" });
            $(".sidebar").animate({left: "-44px"});
            $(".sidecontent")
                   .css("left","-225px")
                   .hide();

        } else if ($theElem.attr('data-toggled') == 'on'){

            $.removeCookie("sidebar");
            $(".sidecontent")
                    .css("left","-225px")
                    .hide();
            $(".sidebar").animate({left: "0px"});
            $theElem.animate({left: "33px"})
                     .removeClass("active")
                     .attr('data-toggled','off');
        }
    });
```

The #mobileBar is only visible on iPad, iPhone etc.

I have tested the function on my desktop too, but it always fires on second click or second tap.

Live click also does not fire on first action.

Comment: Well first you need to think about the absolutly huge amount of calculation it takes to call $(), then you will realize that you can chain calls since most methods in jQuery objects return this, then you will clear your code, and then you will see how much easier it is to find what's wrong (and why it probably is slow).

Comment: Do you have a hover on the bar for desktop? I've seen it where mobile browsers register one click as essentially a hover and the next as the action.

Comment: I have a hover on it's parent node, maybe this is the mistake.